# On an option select dropdown, can I bind to a selected value that wasn't populated by knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a situation where i need to bind to a drop down that is loaded from a static list assembled on the server (synchronously on first page load). Is it possible that I could still bind to the selected value of that list?

Example:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedId">
    <option value = 1>Person 1</option>
    <option value = 2>Person 2</option>
</select>
<p>
    Selected: <strong data-bind="text: selectedId().id"></strong>
</p>
```

With

```
function AppViewModel() {

    this.selectedId = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Currently, nothing is happening and there is no error being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just want: 
    strong data-bind="text: selectedId()"

As far as I know selectedId().id won't return anything because selectedId() is a function not a property.

Comment: If the binding was working, that would return "[Object object]". Currently the binding is NOT working so there is no value in selectedId to begin with

Comment: Seems to work for me here http://jsfiddle.net/G8aru/ (Apologies if I've misunderstood the issue)

Comment: Seems to work for me there too until I apply it to my page! Ugh... not getting any errors. The initial value is showing up but nothing happens when I change the selected value

Comment: Does your observable have a value, and if so, does it change if you inspect it on changing the dropdown value?